# MySQL Update or Add a field

Tags: mysql

So, I have a form that a user inputs information into, after the user inputs the data it inserts it into my MySQL database, so the problem I'm having is that; The user inputer 2 different things X, and Y.

X is never changing, although Y does change every time.
Currently it'll just insert multiple values of X over and over again, making a clutter of the my MySQL table. How can I make it Insert or Update? (I dont want a user side error saying "that's been already added", I want MySQL to update the Value of Y, and Add X & Y if X is already non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) command of MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(c);
```

Comment: C being the Unique column? (in my situation X?)

Comment: Yes. you don't want X to be duplicated, so you should define X as the primary key.

Comment: Ah I see, Though, this would mean removing my auto-increment field?

Comment: You can define UNIQUE index on column X.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, took a bit of research into that link, though I finally got it to work: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Y=VALUES(Y)`